# How to open a firefox bookmark using windows command prompt

Tags: windows, firefox, browser

Lets say I have a Firefox book mark to "http://www.bbc.com" with the name "bbc news".
Is there a way to open this bookmark with firefox using `Windows Run` or `Windows Command Prompt`

Something like

```
firefox "bbc news"
firefox /b "bbc news"
```

Comment: What is the relevance of the page being a bookmark? Does it have to use the bookmark name?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the Firefox [*Command Line Options*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) page,
I can see no way of opening a bookmark by name, instead just open via URL:

```
firefox.exe -url www.bbc.co.uk
chrome.exe "www.bbc.co.uk"
iexplorer.exe "www.bbc.co.uk"
```

Comment: This is unfortunate as I'd like to open an entire folder of bookmarks